# How to know the response at - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection?

Tags: objective-c

`- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` has only one parameter.

connection.

However, I do not see any member of connection that can tell what is the data being returned by the resources.

I checked 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLConnection

If we do 
sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error: we get something in return.

```
  NSData * response= [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:URLRequest returningResponse:&URLResponse error:&error];
    NSString * result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

here, result is what's actually returned.

But what about if we send this request asynchronously?

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement more then just that one callback (for async calls).

Build a buffer in **didReceiveData**, then on the finished event you can use the buffer.

Like so:

```
// in .h NSMutableData *_data;    

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response
{
    _data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init]; // _data being an ivar
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    [_data appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    // handle connection error
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
{
    // do something with _data


}
```